# kivy.NumericProperty does not accept the min() of a column in a pd.DataFrame: Invalid format

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a slider that has as its max value the lowest value found in a column of a pandas dataframe (the dataframe may change during execution). How do I update the value of the NumericProperty (automatically or at least on event)?

I tried connecting the `max` property of the slider to the `min()` value of the `["A"]` and `["B"]` columns both in the KV file and in the python script, but every time, I get an error about invalid format (even though the result is correct and the app works if the `min()` is calculated from hardcoded values rather than the pd.DataFrame).

## **testing.py**

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
import pandas as pd

class Stats(EventDispatcher):
    dt_min_u_freq = NumericProperty(0)

class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = Stats()
        self.data = pd.DataFrame([[1,5],[2,6],[3,7]], columns=["A", "B"])

    def update(self):

        a = min(self.data["A"])
        b =  min(self.data["B"])

        # This works
        # self.stats.dt_min_u_freq =  min(3,5)

        # This doesn't
        self.stats.dt_min_u_freq =  min(a,b)

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestingApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self): 
        self.engine = Engine()
        self.main = MainWindow()
        return self.main


TestingApp().run()
```

## **testing.kv**

```py
# kivy: 1.10.1

<MainWindow>:
    Label:
        text: str(max_freq.max)

    Slider:
        id: max_freq
        max: app.engine.stats.dt_min_u_freq

    Button:
        text: "Push me"
        on_press: app.engine.update()
```

I expect the max value of the Slider to change to one. Instead I get an error:

```
ValueError: Stats.dt_min_u_freq has an invalid format (got 1)
```

Comment: Your posted code runs fine with `self.stats.dt_min_u_freq = min(a, b)` after pressing `Button` and it displayed 1 for `max`.

Comment: Interesting - it does not on my laptop. But good to know the issue is not in the code. I'll try reinstalling stuff then.

Answer (score 0):

The code was correct, reinstalling the dependencies fixed the error. Thanks, @ikolim for checking that the code works!